How to auto scroll a Vue Datepicker when changing to a past date?
I'm currently using Vue Datepicker to create a widget when I can pass any date in the calendar picker. My configuration uses two calendars side by side. For example, assuming today is December 5th, I can pass a range like "last quarter", which would be from "July 1st to Semptember 31st", this range is selected in the calendar, but I have to use the "left arrow" button beside the "November" label to scroll to the selected range.
Is there a way to "auto scroll", or "auto position" the calendar to the selected date? I would like to have the selection always visible in the screen.
<div>
            <VueDatePicker
              range
              :multi-calendars="!isMobile"
              inline
              :enable-time-picker="false"
              select-text="Apply"
              :ui="customStyles"
              @update:model-value="handleDate"
              @range-start="onRangeStart"
              @range-end="onRangeEnd"
              week-start="0"
              v-model="date"
              :max-date="add(new Date(), { days: -1 })"
              month-name-format="long"
            />
          </div>



